# Cucumber::CucumberExpressions::CucumberExpressionError: Single transformer unexpectedly matched 2 values

Tags: ruby, regex, cucumber

My step definition:

```
    Then(/^I create documentation via api( for( (\d+) child(ren)?)?(,? dimIDs (\d+)(, (\d+))?)?(,? levelID (\d+))?)?$/) do |_, _,
                                  children_number, _, _,
                                  dimID1,_,
                                  dimID2, _,
                                  levelID|
.....
end
```

In my feature file the step is:

```
    Then I create documentation via api for 1 child, dimIDs 1111, levelID 27
```

I get an error:

```
Cucumber::CucumberExpressions::CucumberExpressionError: Single transformer unexpectedly matched 2 values - " 1 child" and ", dimIDs 1111"
```

What am I missing? Also could be syntax is different with some updated versions of ruby, cucumber, or selenium? That step was working for sure, but then it started giving the error.

Comment: Did you update from cucumber 2.x to 3.x?